# Banner news in Wordpress is separated?

Tags: html, css, themes, banner

Can you please help me solve the problem with this page https://noviero.com/ which is in wordpress? It is a free theme so there is no customer support.

This banner news gets separated when page is opened, but if I zoom the page or click on Windows Restore down everything on the page gets on the right place?

This is the space between elements on the banner when page is first opened:
[image: This is the space between elements on the banner when page is first opened]

This is how the page looks like after I zoom in then out. Everything gets as it should be:
[image: This is how the page looks like after I zoom in then out. Everything gets as it should be.]

Is there something I could do in CSS or what?

https://noviero.com

Comment: banner divs has inline css for`height`, may be height is come using jquery, so you need to check that

Comment: Where can I do that?